# Phpmyadmin - Can I add new records where the id starts at 1 and the previous id 1 becomes id 2?

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a site where I'm constantly adding new links. The links are organized in a mysql database with id being the main index starting at 1. I only want to display the top five links from the database on my site so, in my php code I assign the database to an array so I can only call the top 5 links to the site. My problem is that every time I add new links to the database I have to change the id numbers manually. I want the newest link to start at id number 1 and the one below that to automatically become id number 2 and so on. Is there a way to do that or is there a better way to organize my database?

Comment: Leave ids as is, instead use this query `select * from table order by id desc limit 5`

Comment: If you're using an autoincrement id as anything other than a unique key, then you're doing it wrong

Comment: I agree with what @MarkBaker said. If you need to fix anything with autoincremented ids the table data needs to get backed up, then you have to drop and re-insert the table then after re-import the backed-up data. However, this should pretty much never need to be done as it defies the purpose of autoincrement. What you probably need is to create a new table field which is not the primary key which stores your active link ids.

Answer (score 1):

dont make any changes to the id(if you're auto incrementing),just modify your Mysql Query to retrieve data from your table by ID in descending order.

`SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5`